# mysql how to sum time in columns

Tags: mysql

I want to sum the columns `late_am_in`, `late_am_out`, `late_pm_in`, `late_pm_out` and the result to total_hours 
column.

```
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_in, '%H:%I') - TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE
(late_pm_out, '%H:%I')))) AS total_hours
```

The data type of my columns are varchar.

thanks!

[image: sum time in mysql]

I want to achieve like this:
[image: want to achieve]

Comment: Can you share the desired output here?

Comment: Shouldn't the subtraction be the other way? Subtract out from in to get the amount of time they were in.

Comment: hi i just want to get the total hours by adding the column: late_am_in, late_am_out, late_pm_in, late_pm_out. it is possible in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this does it work.

```
SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_in, '%H:%i'))) + (TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_in, '%H:%i')))) AS total_hours
```

Heres how you can update the table to calculate the total hours

```
    Update Test SET total_hours = SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_in, '%H:%i'))) + (TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_in, '%H:%i'))))
```

Heres how you can calculate the total hours when inserting the values

```
INSERT INTO Test
    (`id`, `late_am_in`, `late_am_out`, `late_pm_in`, `late_pm_out`, `total_hours`)
VALUES
    (7, '14:15', '16:15', '18:15', '19:19', SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_am_in, '%H:%i'))) + (TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_out, '%H:%i')) -  TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(late_pm_in, '%H:%i')))))
;
```

Comment: Hi It's not working. please note my columns are varchar. Thanks

Comment: Of course it works, the issue you are have is that you have blank late_am_in and late_am_out. The time_to_sec for those are null and therefore the overall out put for that row is null and you cant sum null.

Comment: There we go try it now. no more nulls. the str_to_date will handle it.

Comment: hi sir i think we are not on the same page. I updated the question with an image on how i want to achieve the result.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. Is it okay now.